# Can I safely cut these wires and leave in the wall?

Tags: electrical, receptacle

I want to remove these two faceplates and have them plastered and painted over:

[image]

The top is obviously a Foxtel outlet (we have a satellite dish on the roof that I'll also be removing at some point) and the bottom has some ancient media connectivity along with Ethernet that isn't hooked up to this room anyway.

My intuition about these things is that they are just passive wires and I can just remove the faceplates, cut the wires, and leave them in the wall (I'll likely pull them up when I'm in the loft at some point later). However, I just want to be really sure I'm not creating a hazard by doing this.

Can anyone confirm that it is safe to do this?

Comment: If it was in NA would say yes, since they are consider low voltage wires.  I do not know AU code, so you need to check with the locals and make sure it is legal for you to touch them.

Comment: Anything non-powered is legal, so regular Ethernet is fine but not PoE (which it's not). The other wires I assume are non-powered.

Comment: "Some ancient media connectivity". Umm... that's the same RJ56/coax cable connection as is on the Foxtel panel above it. _And now I feel old. Thanks. :/_

Comment: Remember when that was the new fangle type connections.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In most areas, low voltage communication wires are not a real safety concern and have very limited reference in the electrical code - primarily to make sure you *don't* put them together with regular AC power lines.

However, for the sanity of the next owner, I highly recommend identifying the other end of the wires and disconnecting those wires from any infrastructure (distribution panels, ethernet switches, etc.). If you really want to be nice, label the other ends to identify the rooms they go to. But the main thing is to disconnect them because otherwise the next owner may try to find the other end *still installed and accessible*, and also long lengths of wire connected on only one end can cause interference, act as an antenna or do other funny things that are not always so easy to troubleshoot.

Comment: Odds are good that once the face plates are removed, the cables will be screwed to identical jacks on the other side. They could just be unscrewed and replaced with a blank cover plate. Of course, if OP is going to plaster/drywall/whatever to _permanently_ hide them, then pulling is good.

Comment: @FreeMan Yes and no. The other end could have 10 cables all going out of one big hole in the wall into a patch panel or other structured wiring system. Or they could end up in a bunch of identical jacks. No way to guess, but easy to figure out on-site.

Comment: Thank you. Yes, I have 2 x 5 outlet Ethernet in study, so will disconnect points 5 and 10. Actually, I had an electrician out to do this originally and only two ports are used of those 10, and he may well have already disconnected them. Will check and pull out those unused cables regardles.